# Can not access quorum's contract from webpage *CORS*

Tags: cors, blockchain, ethereum, web3js, quorum

I am getting following error on browser's console while accessing contracts.

> Failed to load http://localhost:22000/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I fix it?

Following is code:

```
    var output = web3.eth.coinbase;
    $('#candidateName').text(output);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding --cors flag while starting geth

Answer (score 0):

You've been bitten by CORS! Your JavaScript won't be able to read this page without exploiting a security vulnerability in the web browser, but your server can easily proxy it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome browser extension  control access origin to solve the issue. Another way is to use firefox browser.